# How do people feel about a PM2.5 tag and this wiki excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I have recently created [pm2.5](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm2.5) and have it on 3 questions so far.

**update:** 8 questions now.

I have also written the following tag Wiki excerpt:

> PM2.5 is one size classification of airborne particulate matter, but has become a popular catch phrase for any small-sized particulate matter relevant both to atmospheric heating/cooling (as a greenhouse "gas") due to their high thermal emissivity and sunlight absorption, and as a pollutant with health consequences. Other particle sizes can use this tag as well, including PM10, PM1, PM0.1

How do people feel about this? Okay, not okay? better wording?

Answer (score 3):

I like it up until "Other particle sizes can use this tag as well...". I find it annoying but that's is not the way how tags seem to work: there isn't a nested hierarchy of tags, so each one should use its own tag.

For instance it would be nice if the tag [cryosphere](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryosphere) somehow embraces [glaciology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glaciology), [permafrost](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permafrost), [sea-ice](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-ice), etc. But that is not possible. Only tag synonyms are allowed.

Maybe a better solution in this case is to have a more general tag, like "airborn-particulates" or something alike. Then we can make PM0.1, PM1, PM2.5, and PM10 all synonyms to it.

In that way, if someone try to add the tag PM2.5 it will be instead offered "airborn-particulates" in the pop-up list.

Comment: okay here's the current status; the `pm2.5` tag is now on [eight questions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm2.5) while the earlier `particulates` tag is on [four questions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particulates) (including perhaps some it shouldn't be?) According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/303080) one solution is to 1) get five questions to have both tags, and (cont.)

Comment: 2) someone with 1250 rep or more (this is beta) to suggest that `pm2.5` *become a synonym to* `particulates` from the [particulates page](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particulates). It will show up in the review queue I think, and after a few votes, `particulates` will be the tag and `pm2.5` will forever behave as a synonym. You can start typing it, and `particulates` will appear instead as the default. Wait, it has to be done with someone with "5 score in this tag" which apparently I don't have https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ9Nl.png

Comment: @uhoh You should have more than 5 score in that tag from your answer to this question only: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16685/11908
If you recently re-tagged that question maybe you need to wait for the scores to be computed again.
I don't have any score in particulates, so I can't create the synonym either (I tried).

Comment: @uhoh OK, I just realized that only answers upvotes counts towards your tag score (not the associated reputation), so you have only score 3 for particulates, you need two more votes on that answer I mention above to be able to create synonyms, and you already have my upvote.

Comment: Okay we'll just have to keep an eye on it, or look for volunteers, or perhaps moderator assistance can work here as well. Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: I'm in favour of `particulates`, at least unless we start to get a lot (hundreds) of questions about one particular particulate size.